# Set a struct value inside a struct inside a vector given as void *

Tags: c, pointers, vector, struct

I am not able to set a vector value which is into a struct inside a struct inside a vector given as a void pointer. Is a bit complex.

These are the definitions:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short int sensor_value[3];
    double accelerometer[3];
} Accelerometer_t;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned short int sensor_value[3];
    double magnetometer[3];
} Magnetometer_t;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned short int sensor_value[3];
    double gyroscope[3];
} Gyroscope_t;

typedef struct 
{
    unsigned short int roll;
    unsigned short int pitch;
    unsigned short int yaw;
} IGRF_diff_t;

typedef struct
{
    Magnetometer_t mag;
    Gyroscope_t gyr;
    Accelerometer_t acc;
    IGRF_diff_t state;
} Attitude_t;
```

I want to set the value of a sensor with data from a file. I'm using this:

```
fscanf(filefd, "%hx %le", &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].acc.sensor_value[0], &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].acc.accelerometer[0]);
fscanf(filefd, "%hx %le", &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].acc.sensor_value[1], &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].acc.accelerometer[1]);
fscanf(filefd, "%hx %le", &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].acc.sensor_value[2], &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].acc.accelerometer[2]);
fscanf(filefd, "%hx %le", &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].mag.sensor_value[0], &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].mag.magnetometer[0]);
fscanf(filefd, "%hx %le", &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].mag.sensor_value[1], &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].mag.magnetometer[1]);
fscanf(filefd, "%hx %le", &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].mag.sensor_value[2], &((Attitude_t *)buffer)[i].mag.magnetometer[2]);
```

buffer is a void * correctly allocated as Attitude_t*1, in this case (but the 1 can vary), i has the value 0, and the data is being read properly (tested with "normal" variables). But this maze of pointers, conversions, vectors and structs doesn't work. It only sets acc.sensor_value[0], acc.accelerometer[0], mag.sensor_value[0], mag.magnetometer[0], and so on. The rest are zero, or weird values (I suppose values by default).

Comment: I suggest you create another variable out of the `void *` instead of the *horrible* typecasting. `Attitude_t *tmp = buffer;` -- then you will be able to use the more readable, cast-less versions: `&tmp[i].acc.sensor_value[0]`, etc.

Comment: Why are you using a void? Why don't you check the return value of fscanf?

Comment: @CharlieBurns This is intended to be a generic function for doing the same with other (simpler) structs. Instead of having seven or eight functions, we have one with a "type" parameter. I should also be checking the result of fscanf, true, but in this case, the values are properly read, because I checked it with "normal" variables. They are not properly assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nearly always, after hours of struggling, when I arrive here and ask, I have sudden realizations and solutions. This time was the printing function (I have a reading and a printing "generic" functions for this structs) that wasn't working properly and was making me mad. Now it works perfectly (even in the horrible version).

Thank you for your comments.